# Wrong Pressure #yahoo-weather-api

Tags: yahoo, weather, pressure

I get currently a pressure of 32306.16 Millibar. What's going on wrong?

My request contains u='c'

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20u='c'%20and%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22Aalen%2C%20de%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Yahoo has a Problem for at least one and a half year (!):
https://knx-user-forum.de/forum/supportforen/openhab/903343-weather-binding-holt-kein-wetter-von-yahoo/page2

Good Morning Yahoo!

Answer (score 0):

I think Yahoo got it wrong. So if you requested u=c then it returns millibars but it is not expected value you must convert it to inch then you got the real millibars.

then if you requested u=f then it returns in but it is not as expected value it is a millibars so you must again convert it to an in.